# copy driver include file to linux folder

Tags: drivers, kernel-modules, buildroot

I'm using buildroot for my embedded socfpga system. I have successfully written a driver and an app to test it, following [BR usermanual](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#adding-packages) :

- my_driver_dma : the driver
- my_dma        : the app

The problem I have is that I must include "my_driver_dma.h" in "my_dma.c" to use the dedicated driver functions.

I haven't figure out how to find the "my_driver_dma.h" file automaticcaly. To compile it and for test purpose, I have it copied into the "my_dma" folder but this is not reliable.

I assume that I must copy the include file somewhere like "/build/linux-socfpga-4.16/include/linux/" folder but I don't know how to do it.

***What shall I change in my files to have the include file "my_driver_dma.h" automatically seen in my_dma app source file "my_dma.c" ?***

Here are my files :

> my_apps/my_dma/Makefile
>   my_apps/my_dma/my_dma.c
>
> my_drivers/my_driver_dma/Makefile
>   my_drivers/my_driver_dma/my_driver_dma.c
>   my_drivers/my_driver_dma/my_driver_dma.h
>
> BR/package/my_apps/my_apps.mk
>   BR/package/my_apps/Config.in
>   BR/package/my_apps/my_dma/my_dma.mk
>   BR/package/my_apps/my_dma/Config_in
>
> BR/package/my_drivers/my_drivers.mk
>   BR/package/my_drivers/Config.in
>   BR/package/my_drivers/my_driver_dma/my_driver_dma.mk
>   BR/package/my_drivers/my_driver_dma/Config_in

**my_apps/my_dma/my_dma.c**

```
#include <my_driver_dma.h>
[...]
```

**my_apps/my_dma/Makefile**

```
#
# sample Makefile for my_dma
#

SRC=my_dma.c
OBJ = my_dma.o
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra
TARGET=my_dma


# rules
all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $^ -o $@

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ)

install:
    cp my_dma $(DESTDIR)/bin/my_dma
```

**my_drivers/my_driver_dma/Makefile**

```
ifneq (${KERNELRELEASE},)

    obj-m  = my_driver_dma.o
else

    KERNELDIR        ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
    MODULE_DIR       ?= $(shell pwd)
    ARCH             ?=
    CROSS_COMPILE    ?=
    INSTALL_MOD_PATH ?= /

all: modules

modules:
    export ARCH=$(ARCH)
    export CROSS_COMPILE=$(CROSS_COMPILE)
    ${MAKE}  -C ${KERNELDIR} SUBDIRS=${MODULE_DIR}  modules

modules_install:
    export ARCH=$(ARCH)
    export CROSS_COMPILE=$(CROSS_COMPILE)
    ${MAKE} INSTALL_MOD_PATH=${INSTALL_MOD_PATH} -C ${KERNELDIR} SUBDIRS=${MODULE_DIR}  modules_install

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.ko *.mod.c .*.o .*.ko .*.mod.c .*.cmd *~
    rm -f Module.symvers Module.markers modules.order
    rm -rf .tmp_versions
endif
```

**BR/package/my_drivers/my_drivers.mk**

```
include package/my_drivers/*/*.mk
```

**BR/package/my_apps/my_apps.mk**

```
include package/my_apps/*/*.mk
```

**BR/package/my_apps/my_dma/my_dma.mk**

```
MY_DMA_VERSION = 1.0.0
MY_DMA_SITE = $(TOPDIR)/my_apps/my_dma
MY_DMA_SITE_METHOD = local
MY_DMA_INSTALL_TARGET = YES
MY_DMA_INSTALL_STAGING = YES

define MY_DMA_BUILD_CMDS
    $(MAKE) CC="$(TARGET_CC)" -C $(@D) all 
endef

define MY_DMA_INSTALL_STAGING_CMDS
    $(MAKE) DESTDIR=$(STAGING_DIR) -C $(@D) install
endef

define MY_DMA_INSTALL_TARGET_CMDS
    $(INSTALL) -D -m 0755 $(@D)/my_dma $(TARGET_DIR)/usr/bin/my_dma
endef

$(eval $(generic-package))
```

**BR/package/my_drivers/my_driver_dma/my_driver_dma.mk**

```
MY_DRIVER_DMA_VERSION = 1.0.0
MY_DRIVER_DMA_SITE = $(TOPDIR)/my_drivers/my_driver_dma
MY_DRIVER_DMA_SITE_METHOD = local
MY_DRIVER_DMA_DEPENDENCIES = linux

define MY_DRIVER_DMA_BUILD_CMDS
    $(MAKE) -C $(@D) $(LINUX_MAKE_FLAGS) KERNELDIR=$(LINUX_DIR) modules
endef

define MY_DRIVER_DMA_INSTALL_TARGET_CMDS
    $(MAKE) -C $(@D) $(LINUX_MAKE_FLAGS) KERNELDIR=$(LINUX_DIR) modules_install
endef

$(eval $(kernel-module))
$(eval $(generic-package))
```

Answer (score 1):

In your buildroot makefile (.mk) add the following in the install section

```
define MY_DRIVER_DMA_INSTALL_TARGET_CMDS
    $(INSTALL) -D -m 644 $(@D)/my_driver_dma.h $(LINUX_DIR)/include/my_driver_dma.h
endef
```

This will do the trick.